# Why won't my Formstack document tags (word doc) read my field Array (Airtable) with the tablerow loop?

Tags: java, zapier, tablerow, airtable, formstack

This is an example of my field data:

```
[{"1A":"Loose cables hanging","1B":"Objects causing potential eye injury to persons. Objects cause unnecessary trip hazards. Objects causing potential damage to existing assets.","1C":"All operatives","1D":2,"1E":3,"1F":6,"1G":"Leave cable lengths secured and wrapped neatly, secure with cable ties and ensure they are placed in a position where they can cause no harm.","1H":1,"1I":3,"1J":3,"1K":"Low"},{"2A":"Damaged components","2B":"Falling from height and the associated risks","2C":"All operatives/ members of public","2D":2,"2E":5,"2F":10,"2G":"Scheduled equipment maintenance, safety checks ahead of usage.","2H":1,"2I":5,"2J":5,"2K":"Low"}]
```

This is an example of my tags:

{tablerow from=$RiskMatrix item=risk}{$risk.1A} {$risk.1B}  {$risk.1C}  {$risk.1D}  {$risk.1E}  {$risk.1F}  {$risk.1G}  {$risk.1H}  {$risk.1I}  {$risk.1J}  {$risk.1K}{/tablerow}

The result in each of my table cells (Formstack doc) is showing

```
{
```

in each cell.
I want the value (string) of each key value pair in my array data to show in my table cells.

Am I doing something wrong with the tags/field data or is this only possible via Zapier/further scripting?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.